# Given N ranges. How many ways are there to take N numbers from these ranges that sums up to a certain value?

Tags: c++, combinatorics

Let we have **N** range **[ L , R ]** . We have to take **N** numbers from these **N** ranges that sums up to a certain value **C**. I need to find how many ways we can do this of course with a MOD value ( e.g. 10<sup>9</sup>+7 )?

For example, Let we have 3 Range . And I have to make **C = 10**.

```
2 5
3 4
2 4
```

So there are in total **24** combination. And there are total **6** ways to make **10** . i.e. [2,4,4],[3,3,4],[3,4,3],[4,3,3],[4,4,2],[5,3,2] .

**Constraints:**

```
0 < N <=110
0 < L, R <=50000
```

Any help will be appreciated .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Any help will be appreciated._ Any attempt, to solve this, _by you_, will be appreciated.

Comment: what have you try ?

Comment: I tried to find a answer in Stackoverflow. But failed. As I don't have any idea that's why I shared it here ? I can do it by running N loops. But it will surely takes much time .

Comment: I thought it can be done with DP or any similar ideas but I can't come up with such type of Ideas .

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a simple approach using dynamic programming. Given `N` Ranges `[L(1),R(1)], [L(2), R(2)], ..., [L(N),R(N)]`, we can compute the Number `f(i,c)` of possibilities to pick one Integer in each of the first `i` Ranges so they sum up to `c`. The values for `f(0,c)` are very obvious:

```
f(0,0) = 1  
f(0,c) = 0 (for all c besides 0)
```

For `f(i+1,c)` assume `L(i+1) <= x <= R(i+1)` is the value we pick from the `i+1`-th list. Then there are `f(i,c-x)` possibilities to pick values from the first `i` lists so the total sum is `c`. Summing over all possible choices of `x` gives us:

```
f(i+1,c) = f(i, c-L(i+1)) + f(i, c-L(i+1)+1) + ... + f(i, c-R(i+1))
```

Then `f(N,C)` is the number you are looking for.

Note using this approach you need to compute about `N*C` numbers `f(i,c)` and need to sum about `R(i)-L(i)` number to compute some `f(i,c)`, so the runtime isn't too great. I would suspect there are much better ways to solve this problem by doing the combinatorics.